# Merge conflict option not show because conflict rows is too far in files

Tags: xcode, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm in merge window with conflicting rows. When is conflict row in left side is near conflict row in right side in the middle is option for "choose left, choose right, choose left then right , choose right then left", but when is to far this option menu is now show. How can I show this options?

[please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd1Vp.png)